# flutter inAppWebview: reacting to click on pdf link

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-inappwebview

I'm trying to use InAppWebview plugin in flutter, works well but when I click on a pdf link it does nothing.

to try that just click on the first or second link in the google search.

nor `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` or `onDownloadStart`

any idea on how to show or how to intercept it?

```
    class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      final String url;
    
      WebViewWidget(this.url);
    
      @override
      _WebViewWidgetState createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
      final Completer<InAppWebViewController> _controller =
          Completer<InAppWebViewController>();
    
      final InAppWebViewGroupOptions _options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
        ),
        android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
          useHybridComposition: true,
          loadWithOverviewMode: true,
          useWideViewPort: false,
          builtInZoomControls: false,
          domStorageEnabled: true,
          supportMultipleWindows: true,
        ),
      );
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return InAppWebView(
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=pdf+example")),
                initialOptions: _options,
                shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, action) {
                  print("override");
                  return Future.value(NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW);
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
                },
                onDownloadStart: (controller, uri) {
                  print("download");
                },
             );
          }),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to do this first
`WebView.shouldOverrideUrlLoading = true` just before runApp is called in main.dart
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebViewOptions/useShouldOverrideUrlLoading.html

Comment: @Rahul that property is not defined for the class WebView, besides is already set to true in cross platform options and it works for normal links, but not for pdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `onDownloadStart` to be called `useOnDownloadStart: true` must be set on `crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions()`. Once that was done the callback was called correctly.